# Deploying YOLOV5 on Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, object-detection, yolo, azure-machine-learning-service, yolov5

I have a YOLOV5 model trained on a custom dataset and I try to deploy it to Azure with a pipeline.

First I tried it with a notebook instance and everything is fine but since I need to automatize it I am try to create a "dataset" on Azure but when I upload the dataset it changes the dataset type (Normally in YOLO it must be like this -images(folder) -labels(folder))

Later tried it with method below:

```
run = Experiment(ws, name='try').submit(src)
run.wait_for_completion(show_output=True)
```

but when I run it I am having the following error

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

I read several guides from Microsoft but none of them includes deploying an object detection model with a custom dataset.

So I am a bit lost, If anybody can guide me I would appreciate it

Comment: When you say "upload dataset", does that mean you made an Azure ML Dataset? If so, what kind? Tabular or File?

Comment: Yes I created an Azure ML Dataset in file type but somehow I couldn't make use of it

Answer (score 0):

Upload your file somewhere else, and download it with `!wget` and if it is a zip, then `!unzip` it. Unlike to Google's Colab, Azure storages files after close the browser.